# Does function inherit variables from modifier?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, modifiers

In a contract where a modifier like this would be reused a lot, is ID inherited by the function that uses the modifier? If not, this check would need to be in the function. If yes, is there any drawbacks from putting `uint ID` in the modifier?

```
modifier isMember (address _foo) {
  uint ID = memberIndex[_foo];
  require(ID != 0); 
  _;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a function cannot access the variables in the modifier.

The compiler will show an error

```
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
        uint b = ID;
                 ^
```